# After Software update on 7/9/2014 I cannot get to the desktop screen

Tags: drivers, ati, update-manager, screen

System info
MotherBoard: Asus z87-c
CPU: Intel i5-4670k
Memory: 8gb corsair 1600hz
Network card: Asus PCE-AC68, Realtek PCIe GBE(built into motherboard)
Sound Card: external ARCAM irDAC, Asus Essence STX.
Graphics card:msi R9-290x.
mouse: logitech G500
Keyboard: StealSeries APEX Gaming Keyboard
Monitors: Dell U2713HM, Eizo Foris FG2421.
Samsung SSD 840: windows 8.1pro is installed on this one.
Western Digital WD2500jd: Ubuntu 14.04 is installed on this one.

All the drivers I am using are what came with the installation. The only difference is that I am using AMD Propietary Driver 14.4.

I am new to linux and have been using Ubuntu Trusty for a few months. After a few teething problems I have been enjoying it until today (8th September 2014). I noticed the day before there was software update. I did cast my eyes over what was being updated and the only thing that stood out was "x-org" i think it was which think is something to do with the open source graphics driver. But I wasn't using that so thought nothing of it.

The next day when I turned it on I got the normal GRUB and it started booting as normal however,  I saw the Ubuntu logo and then a blank screen.

I have had problems with linux and the eizo monitor before. and unplugged it and just used the Dell. This didn't solve the problem this time.

I have searched for a solution i.e. changing ro to rw in the GRUB. 
I saw one where you purge or reinstall the frglx driver. but when I go onto the recovery mode and select command line. and try using the sudo apt-get... I get warning and error messages. something about read and write errors.

Is there anyway to go back a day or undo the update?
I have the live CD can I use that to fix it in anyway?

Update:
I gave up, and reinstalled ubuntu. and setup it up them same way before with using the latest driver from amd. I ran the software update and the same problem occured. after the ubuntu logo i just get a blank screen. so it is definitely repeatable.